# Grub menu is not displayed

Tags: 14.04, grub2

Previously I used dual boot Ubuntu12.04 and Windows8. I updated to 14.04 due to which my grub menu shows 12.04, 14.04 and windows 8. I removed windows8, yet the grub menu shows it.
So I removed the windows8 from the ***/boot/grub/grub.cfg*** menu. There happened some error due to which now the grub screen is  not displayed. 
How can I reinstall or reconfigure it?

Answer (score 1):

To re-configure Grub run `sudo update-grub` in a terminal. This will check your partitions and will generate a new `grub.cfg` file. This is also stated at the top of the file you edited:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#
```

To configure your `grub` use the file located at `/etc/default/grub`